# Learning Differentiable Manifolds prior to Classical Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is it possible to study Differentiable Manifolds from Lee's "Introduction to smooth manifolds" before studying classical differential geometry from DoCarmo's text or Kristopher Tapp's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces".

Right now I'm hearing two sides, with one saying that Differentiable Manifolds doesn't really tie in with Classical Differential Geometry and the other opposing side states that its necessary to understand Classical Differential Geometry to supposedly help with intuition.

In this case I'm wondering what side is right in terms of what course of action to take. Study Differentiable Manifolds first then go back to studying classical differential geometry or start in the other direction?

I currently understand Topology, Abstract Algebra, Real Analysis, Linear Algebra.

Comment: It's possible to learn Lee's book first. It might seem fairly abstract but that might be ok. You can always try to read Lee then backtrack or read something else if you're having trouble.

Comment: Given your current background, moving straight to manifolds shouldn't be awfully difficult. Your knowledge from multivariable calculus may even be sufficient to develop intuition for surfaces and manifolds (surfaces are parametrized sets with two independent variables, manifolds make this definition rigorous). If you ever get stuck, I strongly recommend Loring Tu's _Introduction to Manifolds_. It's an easy read, but thorough and extremely well written with a healthy amount of background material in the appendix and early chapters. Good luck!

Comment: I'll add one more thing. This will take longer but I think will be ultimately extremely beneficial, and that's to read Lee's _Introduction to Topological Manifolds_ first. The early chapters will be easy if you've read Munkres, but be sure you're well acquainted with product and quotient spaces, covering spaces, and partition of unity.

Comment: Tu's "Introduction to Manifolds" is nice but my only qualm is he lacks many diagrams in most sections to aide in intuitive understanding compared to Lee's book "Smooth Manifolds" that contains many diagrams. Would it be productive to use Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" alongside Tu's Manifolds text?